# Changing background size of an a href link

Tags: css, colors, background, href

How do you change an a href link background size? Like for example, you make an a href, then you put a background color on it. But the background color is thin. How do you make it bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were searching for the padding. It's called padding, not the size of the element.

Consider a simple example:

```css
a{
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">test</a>
```